# Admob integration for android

Tags: admob

How to read real add on android device.
The sample add are appear on the emulator but when i try it on real device it does not work.
please help me, what i am doing wrong, reply.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

check in your xml

replace `/res/ with /lib/` in your custom layout `nampespace` `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android`" will be

xmlns:yourApp="`http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.yourAppPackege.yourClass`"

also in Manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
```